# how to animate (flip) image views by its own(without a button) in android?

Tags: android

I have a layout in which i am using 6 image views and all of these 6 image views flip or animate simultaneously when I press a button.
Now i want two things to happen:
  1)all these image views should flip on its own say after 2 seconds without the help of a button.
  2)all the image views should not flip  simultaneously but at different times. Lets say one image view flips after 1 sec ,some views flip after 2 seconds and some after 3 seconds and thus the image views would appear to be flipping on the screen at all times or as long as the screen is not changed.

how to achieve this.Please guide.
Here's the code that i have written to flip the image view on button click.

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity  implements OnClickListener, AnimationListener {

private Animation animation1;
private Animation animation2;
private boolean isBackOfCardShowing = true;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FF0000")));

    animation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.to_middle);
    animation1.setAnimationListener(this);
    animation2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.from_middle);
    animation2.setAnimationListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    v.setEnabled(false);
    ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).clearAnimation();
    ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).setAnimation(animation1);
    ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).startAnimation(animation1);

    ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2)).clearAnimation();
    ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2)).setAnimation(animation1);
    ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2)).startAnimation(animation1);

    ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3)).clearAnimation();
    ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3)).setAnimation(animation1);
    ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3)).startAnimation(animation1);

    ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView4)).clearAnimation();
    ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView4)).setAnimation(animation1);
    ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView4)).startAnimation(animation1);

    ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView5)).clearAnimation();
    ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView5)).setAnimation(animation1);
    ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView5)).startAnimation(animation1);

    ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView6)).clearAnimation();
    ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView6)).setAnimation(animation1);
    ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView6)).startAnimation(animation1);
}

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    if (animation==animation1) {
        if (isBackOfCardShowing) {
            ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).setImageResource(R.drawable.back);
            ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2)).setImageResource(R.drawable.back);
            ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3)).setImageResource(R.drawable.back);
            ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView4)).setImageResource(R.drawable.back);
            ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView5)).setImageResource(R.drawable.back);
            ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView6)).setImageResource(R.drawable.back);
        } else {
            ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).setImageResource(R.drawable.aboutus);
            ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2)).setImageResource(R.drawable.privacy);
            ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3)).setImageResource(R.drawable.conv_up);
            ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView4)).setImageResource(R.drawable.volunteer);
            ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView5)).setImageResource(R.drawable.share);
            ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView6)).setImageResource(R.drawable.rateus);
        }
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).clearAnimation();
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).setAnimation(animation2);
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).startAnimation(animation2);

        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2)).clearAnimation();
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2)).setAnimation(animation2);
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2)).startAnimation(animation2);

        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3)).clearAnimation();
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3)).setAnimation(animation2);
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3)).startAnimation(animation2);

        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView4)).clearAnimation();
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView4)).setAnimation(animation2);
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView4)).startAnimation(animation2);

        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView5)).clearAnimation();
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView5)).setAnimation(animation2);
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView5)).startAnimation(animation2);

        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView6)).clearAnimation();
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView6)).setAnimation(animation2);
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView6)).startAnimation(animation2);
    } else {
        isBackOfCardShowing=!isBackOfCardShowing;
        findViewById(R.id.button).setEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity  implements OnClickListener, AnimationListener {

private Animation animation1;
private Animation animation2;
int current = 0;
int[] imageViewIds ={R.id.imageView1,R.id.imageView2,R.id.imageVie3,R.id.imageView4,R.id.imageView5,R.id.imageView6};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FF0000")));

    animation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.to_middle);
    animation1.setAnimationListener(this);
    animation2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.from_middle);
    animation2.setAnimationListener(this);

   playLoopingAnimations();
}

playLoopingAnimations();
{
    ((ImageView)findViewById(imageViewIds[current])).clearAnimation();
    ((ImageView)findViewById(imageViewIds[current])).setAnimation(animation1);
    ((ImageView)findViewById(imageViewIds[current])).startAnimation(animation1);
}

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) 
{
  current++;
  if(current==imageViewIds.lenghth())
  current=0;
  playLoopingAnimations();
}

@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) 
{

}

@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) 
{

}

}
```

I think this set-up can be modified a bit more to hit the nail on its head!

Comment: Thanks  for your help.. Your code did help me.I had to modify it a bit  to give a interval between the flipping of image views.Thanks Anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use class `CountdownTimer`.

The first parameter is how many milliseconds the timer should run, the second is how many milliseconds is one *Tick*.
`onTick` executes every time 1 *Tick* is completed and `onFinish` executes when the countdown finishes.

I think you can use this creatively to achieve your result.

CountdownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(2000, 1000) {

```
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
               //Do something every tick
            }

            public void onFinish() {

               //Do something when timer finishes
            }
         }.start();
```